# Using VGA-in to screen from the VGA-out of a laptop

Tags: screen-recorder

I have this old laptop that is able to play this old game that won’t work on my desktop. However, it is to slow to run a screen recording program in the background. My desktop has a VGA-in for use with a document reader and I’m now wondering if the VGA-in port could be used to screen record the VGA-out from the laptop.

The laptop would duplicate the display from its screen to the VGA-out. I just need video capture, I don’t need sound.

Comment: What have you actually tried so far?

Comment: I tried to see if my laptop would think the VGA-In on my desktop was an external display but nothing happened. The desktop that has the VGA-in is over a decade old so running apps may be a problem on it

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Freeseer** for this.

> Freeseer (pronounced free-see-ar) is a free, open source,
> cross-platform application that captures or streams your desktop

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXs8beuvvrM) is a tutorial video on how to set it up to **capture output from a VGA cable**.

[Here](https://freeseer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-start.html) is a link to the quickstart guide to use the software